# How to push request a CSRF Token in k6 performance testing tool - ReferenceError

Tags: request, csrf, load-testing, k6

I am quite new to k6 and load testing and I could not figure out why I am not able to push a token from one request to another, to test the login process in a Laravel-built web app. I hope somebody can help me out with this issue.

So my script looks like the following:

**First request from where I want the token:**

```
import { parseHTML } from 'k6/html';
import { sleep, group, check } from "k6";
import http from 'k6/http'

export const options = {}

export default function main() {
  let response

   group('page_1 - http://localhost:81/login', function () {
    response = http.get('http://localhost:81/login', {
      headers: {
        host: 'localhost:81',
        'user-agent':
          'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
        accept:
          'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        cookie:
          'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InY5ckZiaGdFTkI4Q0YyRi8rdmtyNUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT0NjZXlWWVBubTE5Zjh6cXBmNmZFWTdZKzBjVXlEOGhheGR0aVUybURSSGRZbEFmQ0N2RW5BQ3pOYzBQUXgweXhUaGNpRDhrcTV5SHBJUkEvU0FYTmN3eCswYTFsVnhQdk8wL1dkeHMvOTNXRTU4dnk2WjJ0QWFCSWdyQzEwQkwiLCJtYWMiOiIyODI1YmFkMDI1MzlkOGY4ODEyMDg4YWU5M2I5MWE3NmI3Yjg2ODczYTBkMzhhNmZiZTU5ODNlZDBjOGViNWIzIn0%3D; dev_session=eyJpdiI6ImNGalhPQW9GTWlYLzdsaEg1Qk0zdnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVU5jQ21OZmkyUDVnUmd2WUxUc3Z5dWhRbzBJTm1HWFhmQ1RuNzdFaEpRb1IzdVlIa1VhUkNXYTBlc2IxMHRMajl6UTAzYmFVTHZheEdTV2RrYU84d3pmdEUxYUlkaVFFT3J5YUVWSE1wVklRektqemVmbjhmK3hLWHo2ZmlMYlgiLCJtYWMiOiI3MTQ2ODg0Yjk4YjhhNjg2Yzg1YjllZjdmMWMyNzVkY2ZmNGM1NjAzYWUyN2NlMmE0ZjAwOTAyNWMwNGI2YmM2In0%3D',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'sec-gpc': '1',
      }, 
    })
      
  // Query the HTML for an input field named "_token".
  const elem = response.html().find('input[name=_token]');

  // Get the value of the attribute "value" and save it to a variable
  const token = Elem.attr('value');

  // Now you can concatenate this extracted value in subsequent requests that require it.

  // console.log() works when executing k6 scripts locally and is handy for debugging purposes
  console.log('The value of the hidden field is: ' + token);
  
  check(response, { 
      list_OK: (r) => r.status === 200,
    });
  })
```

**Second request - I want to use the token from the previous request to log in:**

```
    group('page_2 - http://localhost:81/customlogin', function () {
        const url = 'http://localhost:81/customlogin';
        const payload = JSON.stringify({
    _token: `${token}`,
    email: 'user',
    password: '1234',
    });
  const params = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      host: 'localhost:81',
          'user-agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
          accept:
            'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
          'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
          'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          origin: 'http://localhost:81',
          connection: 'keep-alive',
          referer: 'http://localhost:81/login',
          cookie:
            'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImlnZFZCUGF1b1FYUlJOdTJHNDd2Vnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTXhhdnZyQzlPamRFQ21rajdQVEZXcThzWittZndqU2d1L0hyN1BmRTA2a2RBbEpYZUhIUlRpWjh1RWJoQ1Y5dWJoTWVnaXEzZ1NVTjBndG1tenUyN2phY1lMdkIxSzBGek5aYndlSmRxaEhVTGY4WkNCcE1UY3N6YmowUnkrTkciLCJtYWMiOiJlNDIxNjhkYTc1NjYxNTVkNWZhOWViZDYwMGU1ODRkNmQ2ZGU0NjgyMjU5NjIxMzQ0MjYyYzRjMmJkYTVmNjUwIn0%3D; dev_session=eyJpdiI6IndxWXpobW9BUm1GSHNVZkorN0N0OGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSE82by9aRnBXQjFkNG5JMHFkVzUzc3kraUZOYUdIdjNlUGN6a3c2SjBSZy9TaVNxNmRsWnQzMTltMGt0MGQvWUoxQndyQXFvd2theWViNU94Z2FXaXlGTkc4ZVdERGY2KzRpUUZDZDIxNG85UFhhanRiajBCWElmcmthMWE0R3IiLCJtYWMiOiJjMDllMmRmNGJjNDRlMjM2MmZmZTViOWEwZmUzNWQ3MzNjZDI1NWQwYmU3MjE4OTZiMTRhN2U0NWNkMTcxMDAzIn0%3D',
          'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
          'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
          'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
          'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
          'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
          'sec-gpc': '1',
    },
  };
  response = http.post(url, payload, params);
    console.log(response)
    check(response, {
      list_OK: (r) => r.status === 200,
    });
  })
```

After running the script I get an error message saying:

**> ReferenceError: token is not defined**

Thank you for your passionate help!

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct and you should immediately see your scoping problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are defining a variable in the first call to `group` (const token ....` and then try to use it in the second call.

This has nothing to do with CSRF or k6, but with javascript ... and arguably scoping in *most* other languages.

But in order for both functions to see the same variable you will need to define it earlier - so for example next to your `let response` in the start of the `default` function.

Also remove `const`  from the current definition as otherwise it won't work ;)

Comment: Note that you could return the token from the `group` callback and then assign the result of the group. That way you don't have to make the variable visible to multiple (nested) scopes.

Comment: Hi Михаил Стойков,

Thank you for your help!

Now it works fine :) the token is pushed perfectly in the second request, but I’m still getting an error message saying: “status”:419,“status_text”:“419 unknown status”, so the second request fails, something is still not working properly, so I’m working on it, maybe the method of the push request is not ok somehow (?). 

Do you have any idea what should I change in the second request?

Comment: Just figured it out, the "const payload = JSON.stringify" and "const params" are not necessary for the second request. works fine without them!